# facing issue while compiling code

Tags: esp8266

This following error message I am getting while compiling:

```
Arduino: 1.6.8 (Windows 7), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

In file included from C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/opt.h:51:0,

                 from C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/init.h:40,

                 from C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266/IPAddress.h:27,

                 from C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:31,

                 from C:\Users\Shree\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\examples\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266.ino:20:

C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwipopts.h:1301:2: error: #error TCP_MSS must be defined

 #error TCP_MSS must be defined

  ^

C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwipopts.h:2381:2: error: #error LWIP_IPV6 must be defined

 #error LWIP_IPV6 must be defined

  ^

C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwipopts.h:3534:2: error: #error LWIP_FEATURES must be defined

 #error LWIP_FEATURES must be defined

  ^

In file included from C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFiSTA.h:29:0,

                 from C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:34,

                 from C:\Users\Shree\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\examples\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266.ino:20:

C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0/tools/sdk/include/user_interface.h:34:2: error: #error LWIP_OPEN_SRC must be defined

 #error LWIP_OPEN_SRC must be defined

  ^

C:\Users\Shree\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\examples\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266.ino:21:29: fatal error: FirebaseArduino.h: No such file or directory

 #include <FirebaseArduino.h>

                             ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
***************************
```

please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: are all options set in tools menu? it is better to use esp8266 Arduino package 2.4.2 until 2.5.1 is released

Comment: Can you please provide the code?

Comment: at a guess you're including some headers in the wrong order, or haven't included a required header at all ... without code, I'm guessing

Comment: ok I will try with esp866 2.4.2. I am trying to compile example of FirebaseDemo_ESP8266. Yet no any code updated.

Comment: Hey guys I have run my example with esp8266 2.4.2 version now I'm getting following error while compiling- C:\Users\Shree\Desktop\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266ex\FirebaseDemo_ESP8266ex.ino:21:29: fatal error: FirebaseArduino.h: No such file or directory

 #include <FirebaseArduino.h>

                             ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).